# Backbone history and require.js issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

i'm doing an app by backbone and on console of my device appear this error:

```
<!>android.webkit.CallbackProxy 711<!> Uncaught Error: Backbone.history has already been   
 started at file:///android_asset/www/libs/backbone/backbone%201.0.0.js:1363
```

consequently appear this:

```
<!>android.webkit.CallbackProxy 711<!> Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: 
text!templates/singleuser.html
```

and finally this:

```
 http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout at 
 file:///android_asset/www/libs/require/require-1.0.8.js:1634
```

and after the application doesn't work correctly.

Anybody knows the issue?Thanks

Comment: the first error says that Backbone.history has already been started, that means somewhere in your source code you've tried to execute this code 'Backbone.history.start()' twice. Try fix the first error.

Answer (score 2):

The first error indicates that you call `Backbone.history twice`. Scan your code for this snipped `Backbone.history.start()`, add an breakpoint, or the `debugger` statement to figure why it was called twice.

The second error means that you try to load a module but it cant be loaded, most of the time its an typo in the path of the modules you require or an failure in `requirejs.config`. Take a look at the network panel to see which module was requested and gives a `404`.

Comment: Here is an article that described debugging chrome, the other modern browser have the same feature. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: The  errors appear only on eclipse logcat and not in chrome console!So I can't use chrome debugger